# How does the day/night cycle work?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Zones in the world follow a day / night cycle that does not follow real time.
How does it work? Does it have any effect besides the visuals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[My source](http://forum.univers-virtuels.net/topic/18343-article-la-demo-de-gw2-en-details/page__st__200#entry214455) (via the Wiki) for this is in French, but it should work something like this:

> **Are they going to include a day/night cycle?**
>
> Yes. The cycle will be faster than real time. Events and monster
>   spawning will change based on the time of day. Centaurs might attack a
>   camp at dawn, and ghosts haunting an ancient battlefield might only be
>   visible at night. Currently, the cycle lasts 2 hours with 80 minutes
>   of day and 40 minutes of night, but this is subject to change before
>   release.

Sylvari glow at night.

Comment: Nice! Using your source, I've found the same on the GW2 Wiki: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Setting The info looks a bit old, though, since it's from a pre-release FAQ

Comment: As an addition, the day/night cycle is different for the different servers (main/overflow).

Comment: There are also consumables and upgrades that have conditional effects depending on whether it is day or night. (ie. Chili Pepper Popper and Sigil of the Night)